# Запрос в mysql с подзапросом

Tags: mysql

Не работает. Где я ошибся?

```
"UPDATE asset
       SET asset_sum = asset_sum + $paymentIncome - $paymentExpense
       WHERE idasset = (SELECT idasset FROM asset ORDER BY idasset DESC LIMIT 1)");
```

update с вставленным вручную idasset работает.
select отдельно тоже работает.
Вместе не работает. Единственное, что приходит в голову, что и апдейт и селект из одной таблицы запрашиваются. что можно сделать?

Если упростить до такого , то работает

```
UPDATE asset 
SET asset_sum = asset_sum + '$paymentIncome' - '$paymentExpense' 
WHERE idasset = (59)
```

Вот так уже не работает:

```
UPDATE asset 
SET asset_sum = asset_sum + '$paymentIncome' - '$paymentExpense' 
WHERE idasset = (SELECT idasset FROM asset WHERE idasset = 59)
```

Дело в подзапросе. Что не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас должно быть сообщение типа `You can't specify target table 'asset' for update in FROM clause`. Это случай описан в документации (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html). Не разрешено делать селект из той же таблицы, что и обновляемая.
Предлагается использовать multiple-table update, например, так:

```
UPDATE asset,(SELECT idasset maxid FROM asset ORDER BY idasset DESC limit 1) as SelIds
SET asset_sum = asset_sum + (paymentIncome - paymentExpense)
WHERE idasset = SelIds.maxid;
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я так и предполагал, что вопрос в запросе к одной и той же таблице. Буду разбираться.

Answer (score 0):

А вы проверяли, подзапрос возвращает только одно значение, или может несколько? Если не одно, то UPDATE не может определить, какое значение использовать.

Как вариант:

```
UPDATE asset
SET asset_sum = asset_sum + $paymentIncome - $paymentExpense
WHERE idasset = (SELECT idasset FROM asset ORDER BY idasset DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Это будет последняя добавленная запись, если их несколько.

Comment: Отдельно подзапрос я пробовал. Выдает так как надо - один , послдений id. Отдельно апдеёт работает, отдельно подзапрос работает, а вместе нет. Ответ есть, но он не очевиден.